# How can I create this chart in R using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I am using `R` in RStudio and I have the following data frame.

```
df1 <- data.frame(  
  comp = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),  
  Q2_2018 = c(27, 10, 6, 4, 3, 2),  
  Q2_2019 = c(31, 12, 8, 6, 5, 4))
```

I would like to create a chart (from the above data) like the one shown below (excluding the Amazon logo).

I am mostly stuck at drawing the circles with the % changes.

So far,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(magrittr)

melt(df1, id.vars = "comp") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= comp, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

Can it be done with `ggplot2`?

[image: amazon chart]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: At least add this to your question: ```library(ggplot2);
library(reshape2);
library(magrittr);

melt(df1, id.vars = "comp") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= comp, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")```

Comment: @M-- Thanks. I was mostly stuck with the circles showing the % changes.

Comment: @user3115933 Well I said *at least* so your question wouldn't get closed. See the next comment to see what else you could add to your question. With that, and asking how I could add circles instead of labels at the top, I am sure that you would've gotten upvotes (I am not the downvoter, but I understand them). Cheers.

Comment: ```library(ggplot2);
library(reshape2);
library(dplyr);

df1 %>% 
  mutate(mdiff = factor(x =     as.character(round(100*(Q2_2019-Q2_2018)/Q2_2018)),
                       levels = as.character(round(100*(Q2_2019-Q2_2018)/Q2_2018)))) %>% 
  melt(., id.vars = c("comp", "mdiff")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=comp, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  facet_grid(~mdiff, scales = "free_x") +
  theme(panel.spacing.x=unit(0, "lines"), panel.spacing.y=unit(0,"lines"))
```

Comment: @M--I get your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the way:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  gather(year, val, -comp) %>%
  group_by(comp) %>% 
    mutate(change = val / lag(val) - 1) %>%
    mutate(change_lab = if_else(!is.na(change),
                                scales::percent(change, 
                                        accuracy = 1, 
                                        prefix = if_else(change > 0, "+", "-")),
                                NA_character_)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%

  ggplot(aes(comp, val, fill = year, label = val)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(comp, val + 5, size = change), color = "lightgreen") +
  geom_text(aes(comp, val+5, label = change_lab)) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 30) +
  guides(size= F) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: mutate *change* before wide to long to avoid `lag` and other complications. Cheers.